# Grizzly HttpServer clean shutdown got WARNING: GRIZZLY0032

Tags: grizzly

I was trying to clean shutdown grizzly server. I was calling the httpServer.shutdown()

However, while I was running "mvm clean test", I got warnings like

```
Aug 03, 2014 10:39:00 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:8081]
Aug 03, 2014 10:39:00 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Aug 03, 2014 10:39:00 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:8081]
Aug 03, 2014 10:39:00 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.GracefulShutdownRunner run
WARNING: GRIZZLY0030: Shutting down transport TCPNIOTransport[428da4da] in 10,000 SECONDS.
Aug 03, 2014 10:39:00 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.GracefulShutdownRunner run
WARNING: GRIZZLY0032: Primary shutdown thread interrupted.  Forcing transport termination.
```

Here is my code to shutdown the host.

```
protected static void shutdownGrizzlyWebServer(HttpServer grizzlyWebServer) {
if (grizzlyWebServer != null && grizzlyWebServer.isStarted()) {
GrizzlyFuture<HttpServer> future = grizzlyWebServer.shutdown(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
while (!future.isDone()) {
try {
Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException ignore){
System.out.println(ignore);
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what goes wrong here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which Grizzly version are you using?

Comment: I was using <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId<artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId> with version 2.11

Comment: which uses v2.11 jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet, which uses v2.3.16 grizzly-http-servlet, which, I guess is the latest one.

Comment: I just checked the warnings are completely fine, they don't have to cause any problems. We will reduce the logging level.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Is there any way I can override the logging level just for grizzly server?

Comment: specifically for this message you can change the logging level for org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.GracefulShutdownRunner